# Google Admob not showing in product mode for ios (react native)

Tags: ios, react-native, admob, react-native-google-mobile-ads

I am using `"react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^6.3.0",`

It was working when I uses `expo-ads-admob`
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/admob/

But it's deprecated a month ago, and they recommended using `react-native-google-mobile-ads`.

So I migrated from `expo-ads-admob` to `react-native-google-mobile-ads`

It works with test unitID (in emulator and testflight, devices)

It doesn't show with product unitID, and shows error like this

[image]

Code is like below

#### App.tsx

```
   export default function App() {
    
      useEffect(() => {
        request(PERMISSIONS.IOS.APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY)
    
        mobileAds()
          .initialize()
          .then(adapterStatuses => {
            console.info('=== adapter ===', JSON.stringify(adapterStatuses, null, 4))
            // Initialization complete!
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.info('=== err ===', JSON.stringify(err, null, 4))
          });

  }, [])
...
```

#### Admob.tsx

```
const interestialAd = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(unitId); // demo unitId works, but real unitId not working

export const CustomAdMob = (props) => {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = interestialAd.addAdEventListener(AdEventType.CLOSED, () => {
            setLoaded(false)
            interestialAd.load();
        });

        return () => {
            unsubscribe()
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (loaded) {
            interestialAd.show()
        }

    }, [loaded])
...
```

Admob account is created 20 days ago and unit also created 20 days ago.
Admob account payment are verified and app status is `ready`
And there is no privacy issue.

[image]

IOS app is fully published in app store.

I am not sure what's wrong

Answer (score -1):

You handled ? Because it doesn't show me ads either. And before that, they were showing. For me, it does not work on android, they are displayed on the emulator.

Comment: Not an answer to the question

Comment: not solved yet.